# How to use get the height of parent div of a img tag in React?

Tags: javascript, html, height, getboundingclientrect

I am using html canvas with React.js. I want to set my canvas height equal to the height of body so that people can draw on the whole page.

```
import IMG from "../../assets/img/contact-img.jpg";
 constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            width:0,
            height:0
        }
    }
componentDidMount(){
    let newState = {
        width:this.myRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width,
        height:this.myRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height
    };
    this.setState(newState);

}
render(){

        <div>
            <DrawableCanvas width={this.state.width} height={this.state.height}/>
            <img src={IMG} />
        </div>

}
```

My idea is to draw a canvas(width,height=0) firstly. After the whole layout component rendered, we can get the height of the layout and update the canvas.

The problem is I can't get height correctly when there are child  tags.
But I successfully get the height in Chrome console. It seems that when React is rendering component,  tags are ignored.

Comment: Are you looking for the device height, or the height of the parent element of your canvas? You refer to both in your question.

Comment: @Douglas Could you show us how do you handle the dimension properties inside your `DrawableCanvas` component?

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://www.javascriptstuff.com/detect-image-load/

In react, there is difference between being rendered and being loaded.
I tried to get width and height in the componentDidMount() which is wrong.
Because at this moment, all `<img>` have not been loaded.

To solve this problem, please have a look at https://www.javascriptstuff.com/react-image-gallery/

This example shows how to do something (in my case, getting width and height) when `<img>` loaded using `<img onLoad={Fn} onError={Fn}>`